# How to configure Safe Transaction Swagger API with https scheme and domain name

Tags: gnosis-safe

We have deployed safe mainly following [safe-infrastructure repository](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure)
There are multiple services - config, client-gateway, transaction services. Among them config service and transaction service have endpoints exposed via Swagger.

When we try to use txs service API via Swagger, it gives the following -

```bash
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost/txs/api/v1/about/ethereum-rpc/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'X-CSRFToken: YNdS8sRKyQ9eAQDh0iN3s9L06eSLi3CFs00v6m4ig0SWLOJvoM2EMcxa48PEmbQy'
```

Those swagger api are in http schema. **is there any *configuration* that we can change the swagger api endpoint to *https* and with preferred *domain name* ?**

Like the following

```bash
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://safe.stx.org/txs/api/v1/about/ethereum-rpc/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'X-CSRFToken: YNdS8sRKyQ9eAQDh0iN3s9L06eSLi3CFs00v6m4ig0SWLOJvoM2EMcxa48PEmbQy'
```

I can see the [mainnet txs](https://safe-transaction-mainnet.safe.global/) services of Swagger API is using `https` scheme with domain name.

```bash
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://safe-transaction-mainnet.safe.global/api/v1/about/ethereum-rpc/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'X-CSRFToken: SGdMZ5C6hdwLIIZTUxbuXINFY7BxkLp6WPPbpmBC0BwlLGWXxmJkBVIVqwLy4HI7'
```

**Updated**
I added nginx reverse proxy to redirect

```
location /txs {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_connect_timeout   150;
            proxy_send_timeout      100;
            proxy_read_timeout      100;
            proxy_buffers           4 32k;
            client_max_body_size    8m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
}
```

Though I can access txs services via dns name/url. However swagger api doesn't reflect that. It still shows the `http://localhost/txs/api`

How can I update `Base URL` of config service and transaction service?

- Base URL: localhost/cfg/api/v1
- Base URL: localhost/txs/api

**Partial solution**

I'm able to change the baseurl updating the nginx conf. Using `proxy_set_header Host $host;` will update the localhost url to dns.

```bash
location /cfg {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_connect_timeout   150;
            proxy_send_timeout      100;
            proxy_read_timeout      100;
            proxy_buffers           4 32k;
            client_max_body_size    8m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;           
    }
```

However I can't update the transaction service scheme. It is still `http`. I tried with nginx using `proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`.
Also I tried to add `SCHEME=https` in txs.env file to check.

```bash
location /txs {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_connect_timeout   150;
            proxy_send_timeout      100;
            proxy_read_timeout      100;    
            proxy_buffers           4 32k;
            client_max_body_size    8m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            # proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Protocol  $scheme;            
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;           
    }
```

How can I update transaction service scheme to `https`.